# Javascript execute a function after some time elapse

Tags: javascript

I am making a javascript based life game, and I am currently working on a salary system so, for example, every 10 seconds the balance goes up by 1. I've been looking for a while how to do it but never found anything. Here are my codes:

```js
var balance = 100;

function balanceSys(){
    let newbalance = balance + 100;
    balance = newbalance;
    document.getElementById("balance").innerHTML = (balance);
}

function salary(){
    
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Life Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mukta+Malar" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<body>
    <center><h1 class="title">Life Game</h1></center>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="mainTd"><h1 id="balance">0</h1></td>
            <td class="mainTd"><h1 id="state">Begger</h1></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button onclick="balanceSys()">Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried setInterval?

Comment: No, how should I code this?

Comment: google how to use it or look at answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval). It will execute a function every X milliseconds (The second parameter).

You can also take in a parameter for amt to adjust by, and add varying amounts (In this case, I specified 1 in the original interval function, and 100 by default if not specified.

```js
var balance = 0;

setInterval(() => balanceSys(1), 1000);

function balanceSys(amt = 100){
    let newbalance = balance + amt;
    balance = newbalance;
    document.getElementById("balance").innerHTML = (balance);
}

function salary(){
    
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Life Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mukta+Malar" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<body>
    <center><h1 class="title">Life Game</h1></center>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="mainTd"><h1 id="balance">0</h1></td>
            <td class="mainTd"><h1 id="state">Begger</h1></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button onclick="balanceSys()">Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with FrankerZ's method, but you don't want to run `getElementById` every second. Here is a better solution. DOM manipulation is very slow, so try to minimize the impact in performance as much as possible.

```js
function balanceSys(){
    let element = document.getElementById("balance");
    setInterval(() => {
      let newbalance = balance + 1;
      balance = newbalance; 
      element.innerHTML = (balance);
    }, 10000);    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip!